# Statement not firing inside of if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have an if statement but only the 1st of 3 statements inside of the statement is firing.

I used jQuery to hide everything, and then to slide down 1 element. And then change html's background color to black, but it only hides everything.

Statement:

```
if (ccg == 1000) {           
    $("*").hide(); //RUNS :)
    $("#winner").slideDown(1000); //DOES NOT RUN :(
    $("html").css("background-color", "black"); //DOES NOT RUN :(            
}
```

I want all 3 of the statements to run.

Comment: you are hiding all the elements

Comment: your hiding winner before the slide down

Comment: If you're hiding everything first, what's the point of moving things around?

Comment: I want to hide everything else, and then show only the winner element, by sliding it down, and then changing background color to black.

Comment: The problem is entirely due to `$('*').hide()`. That selects *every* element, including the parents of `#winner`. Hiding them will then cause `#winner` to be hidden, despite you making it visible later. You need to correct the `*` selector to something far more specific.

Comment: Like a class for everything else?

Comment: It works! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hiding * you wind up hiding the body, head, basically everything.  So when you use slideDown, the body is literally hidden.  This is a bad practice and will cause unexpected results.  I would suggest hiding the specific intended elements first, then trying this.

```
<p>paragraph</p>
<span id="winner">winnner</span>
```

```
var ccg = 1000;

if (ccg == 1000) {           
    $("#winner").hide(); //RUNS :)
    $("#winner").slideDown(1000); //RUNS :)
    $("html").css("background-color", "black"); //RUNS :)    
}
```